# WPF MVVM. Не обновляется DataGrid при изменении содержимого ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, entity-framework, mvvm

Разрабатываю своё первое приложение с использованием *MVVM*, и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: в окне есть два `DataGrid`, в первом информация о компаниях, во втором об их пользователях. При выборе компании из списка (клик по строке в `DataGrid`) во втором датагриде должны выводиться пользователи, относящиеся к этой компании.

Обновление сделал путём добавления триггера во `View` и специальной команды во `ViewModel`.

Собственно, проблема заключается в том, что `ObservableCollection` с юзерами обновляется, но `DataGrid`, в котором должны выводиться пользователи, не обновляется. Как обновить этот самый `DataGrid`?

View:

```
<Window x:Class="practiceapp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:practiceapp"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="CompaniesDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="237" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CompaniesCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCompany}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="False">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                        Command="{Binding GetUsersByCompanyCommand}"
                    />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </DataGrid>

        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="237" Margin="269,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding UsersCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace practiceapp
{
    class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private RiKContext db;

#region ForCompanies
        private Company _selectedCompany;

        public ObservableCollection<Company> CompaniesCollection { get; set; }

        public Company SelectedCompany
        {
            get { return _selectedCompany; }
            set
            {
                _selectedCompany = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCompany");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region ForUsers
        public ObservableCollection<User> UsersCollection { get; set; }

        private User _selectedUser;
        public User SelectedUser
        {
            get { return _selectedUser; }
            set
            {
                _selectedUser = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedUser");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Commands
        private CommandBase getUsersByCompanyCommand;
        public CommandBase GetUsersByCompanyCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return getUsersByCompanyCommand ??
                  (getUsersByCompanyCommand = new CommandBase(obj =>
                  {
                      Company selectedCmp = SelectedCompany;
                      var foundUsers = db.Users.Where(u => u.CompanyId == selectedCmp.Id);
                      UsersCollection = new ObservableCollection<User>(foundUsers);
                  }));
            }
        }
        #endregion


        #region Constructor
        public ViewModel()
        {
            db = new RiKContext();
            db.Companies.Load();
            db.Users.Load();
            CompaniesCollection = db.Companies.Local;
            UsersCollection = db.Users.Local;
        }
        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите. Изменения в `ObservableCollection<T>` и правда должны автоматически подхватываться привязкой. Но вы в вашем коде не меняете данные внутри коллекции, вы вместо этого подменяете *саму коллекцию*. При этом от самой `ObservableCollection` никакого толку нет, ведь вы не меняете данные внутри. А ваше свойство `UsersCollection` не отправляет NotifyPropertyChanged.

Исправляйте.

Comment: Ошибку осознал, спасибо! :)

Comment: @Julian: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!